# C# Winforms: anchor of a button does not work inside a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor, panel

I have a button inside a panel, and I apply a right-anchor on the button, but it doesn't seem to do anything with the button.

The docking of the panel is set to `None`, autosize is `false`and I have no anchor on it.

The button has a **RIGHT** anchor, autosize is `false` and dock is set to `None`.

These settings doesn't do anything to the button, I expect the button to the anchored to the right.

Panel properties:

[image]

Button properties:

[image]

Comment: Document outline: http://i.imgur.com/CSYz4vF.png Form: http://i.imgur.com/zhBJ5l2.png

Comment: Do you want it to move when you resize the form? Because then you should set an anchor to the panel too, the anchor, anchors to the parent.

Comment: @EpicKip No that is not necessary, I just want the button to be anchored right on the panel

Comment: What do you want your anchor to do?

Comment: Anchor is to keep it in a certain position for when the form resizes (lets say bottom right)

Comment: if you put it in the right side of the panel its already done, you do not have to set an anchor for this. as your Panel does not resize or anything you won't need an anchor

Comment: Anchoring keeps the edges at the fixed position you chose in the designer. it doesn't move a control flush to an edge. The position you show is pretty much in the middle, even leaning to the left!!

Comment: The form does not resize, but the panel can be resized, so for example when I make the panel larger in width, I want the button to stay on the right side

Comment: The keyword here when dealing with anchor is `resize`. If winform size is not change and you are using the same device then I don't see why you are thinking that setting anchor to right on the button would make it move to the right side of the windows form.

Comment: So it has to be done in code? Because I do not want to use docking since it also resizes my button. As I said, the form doesn't resize, but the panel inside the form can be resized.

Comment: No!! Simply move the button to the spot you want it __in the designer__!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what anchoring does, thanks for the replies

Comment: You've just shown properties not actual design of your form.